# How to obtain first subdomain from a domain name

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$url=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // www.abc.alpha.beta.xyz
$url=strtolower($url);
$rwww=str_replace("www.", "", $url);
```

But this results in `abc.alpha.beta.xyz`, the desired result is `abc`. How can I get just the first subdomain, ignoring `www` if present?

Comment: you'd need to substr the http_host with `.`

Comment: `explode` at `.`, and then pick the first array element, or if that should happen to be `www`, the second one …?

Comment: What makes `www` require special treatment compared to `abc` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [**`PHP strpos()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to check if the subdomain URL string contains the word **alpha**

```
// Search substring  
$key = 'alpha'; 
$url = 'http://abc.alpha.beta.xyz';

if (strpos($url, $key) !== false) { 
    echo $key; 
}
```

Not the best solution but might be helpful for you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that, a simple one being:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?? 'www.abc.alpha.beta.xyz';
$parts = explode('.', $host);

$answer = null;
foreach ($parts as $subdomain) {
    if ($subdomain === 'www') {
        continue;
    }
    $answer = $subdomain;
    break;
}

echo "The answer is '$answer'";
```

Which would output:

```
The answer is 'abc'
```

Be aware that this is a very naïve approach and will return `example` for the input `www.example.com` - which isn't a subdomain.